# Matlab - for loop generating vector of ratio of fibonacci numbers

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a for loop in Matlab that will print the ratio of successive Fibonacci numbers F(n+1) / F(n) for n = 3, ..., 20. I want this to illustrate the convergence to the golden ratio.

I have this as code (new to Matlab):

```
f(1) = 0
f(2) = 1
ratio = zeros(1,20);  %Initialize row vector that will contain the ratio's

for n = 3:20
    f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2);
    ratio(n) = ratio(f(n+1)/f(n)); % Update row vector after every iteration
end

ratio
```

I'm getting an error though, having to do with matrix dimensions. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sure about `f(n+1)`?  Also, why are you indexing `ratio` on the right-hand side?

Comment: I think you meant `ratio(n) = f(n)/f(n-1);`

Comment: Ah, should I let it run to 19 then? Also I'm indexing ratio because I want every zero (every component) in the vector ratio to be overwritten by the  ratio of the fibonacci's, every iteration.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks ThP!

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to calculate ratios in a loop:

```
n = 20;
f = zeros(n,1);
f(1) = 0;
f(2) = 1;

for k = 3:n
    f(k) = f(k-1) + f(k-2);
end

ratio = f(3:end)./f(2:end-1);
```